# How to get special section values with PHP?

Tags: wordpress

While posting an article, I write the following section value.

Link
http://www.examplesite.net/

How can I get this value with PHP? (like echo get_option('link', 'articleID'))

Comment: your link is linking to a porn site... modify it xD

Comment: Anyway at least I, don't understand your question pretty well

Comment: When you write an article, you can edit some special section values at below. Such as: Icon - http://www.examplesite.net/icon.png so you can use these values on your themes. (e.g get_option('icon') while posting news with pictures, so you can get icon path like this.)

Basically, I wonder how can I obtain such daha using PHP because I will change my blogging theme a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about "custom fields" which are a built-in way to include additional custom metadata with Wordpress posts and pages.

Each custom field is a key / value pair - in your example the key would be "Link" and the value is the URL.

You can access these using the template tag `get_post_meta()` like so:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Link', true); ?>
```

The first argument specifies the post (depending on the query/loop in your template you might need to replace `$post->ID` with `get_the_ID()` instead), the second specifies the key "Link" and the third option tells it to return as a string.